# Why React Js default page is not loading while giving the command npm start?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have given the following command for running reactproject.

G:\Node.js> cd reactproject
G:\Node.js\reactproject> npm start

After giving the command, I get the following error.

Starting the development server...

```
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

  Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:238:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactproject@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactproject@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Inter_Wave\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-22T10_51_19_865Z-debug.log    ^
```

Comment: did you ran `npm install` before?

Comment: Yes. I also tried giving command npm cache clean and npm install. I created the reactproject app using npx command.

Answer (score -1):

Cleaning Cache and Node_module are not enough. Follow these steps:

1. `npm cache clean --force`
2. delete `node_modules` folder
3. delete `package-lock.json` file
4. `npm install`

It works for me like this.
You can also try `npm cache verify`
Hope it helps.

Comment: it did not work for me. i got some errors after giving npm install command,                                                               npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Inter_Wave\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-22T11_37_29_641Z-debug.log

Comment: check your directory if it has a package.json file and it is in the right place cause it is looking for it and thats why giving you error.

Comment: No, I have checked. Actually, I have got the same problem defined in my question.